# How to delete a table after a period of inactivity?

Tags: sql-server

For the purpose of my project I cannot use session based temp tables. They need to be persistent but automatically deleted after a certain period of inactivity (no CRUD performed). Is this at all possible?

Comment: *Sort of*. You can use `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` to track activity, and a scheduled job to act on this data. However, this view is cleared on every restart of SQL Server, so you'd need extra care to make sure you don't delete tables inadvertently. Reading this data is not too efficient either. You're probably better off explicitly coding this in your data layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SQL Server Agent` to Schedule a Job that calls a Stored Procedure that does this work for you. ([How to Schedule a Job?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx))

**How do you identify the tables that have not updated since X amount of time ?**

Use this Query:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName, last_user_update,
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID('DatabaseName')
AND OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%%' -- Here is the template name for your tables
AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, last_user_update, GETDATE()) > 10 -- Last updated more than 10 minutes
```

Now that you have the tables to be deleted, you can use whatever logic you want to DROP them (Cursor, While, Procedure)

Comment: This will fail after a server restart.

Comment: I still consider this the best option, for me, since I don't care about server restarts (I clean all my temp tables on server restart anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is. Write it into your program layer.

AUTOMATICALLY - within SQL Server: no. Well, you cold use the agent to start a script regularly.

Tracking what "inactivity" means - your responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

You need save modification date of this table somewhere (for example in the same table or in another special table) and then you can create job, which checks last modification date and then drops the table.

Comment: Abovmentioned **sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats** is better solution. But this view is recreated after sql service restart. In this case you can save data from **sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats** into another permanent table periodically and after restarting server information about index  usage won't be deleted. And then you can use this "statistic" table to decide if your table should be deleted.